# Swift is unable to type infer variable containing closure that returns Bool

Tags: swift, closures, type-inference

I have a method, and it contains the following:

```
let downloadNextPagination = {
    if current.integerValue < amount.integerValue {
        if current.integerValue != amount.integerValue - 1 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

if downloadNextPagination() {
    // Do something
}
```

This code will not compile: Unable to infer closure return type in current context

Changing the definition of downloadNextPagination to

```
let downloadNextPagination: () -> Bool
```

fixes the issue. Question is: Why can Swift not work out the correct type of the closure here? All code paths return Bool, yet this can't be worked out? Is this a fundamental limitation / am I missing something in my understanding here, or is this simply a question of improving the compiler's type inference ability and something like this may well work come Swift 3?

Comment: The return type is inferred automatically only for "single-expression closures" (or from the context). Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113457/using-map-in-swift-to-change-custom-struct-properties for a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift can currently infer only single-return closures. You can rewrite your closure to:

```
let downloadNextPagination = { 
    return current.integerValue < amount.integerValue && current.integerValue != amount.integerValue - 1 
}
```