# Swift block syntax failure to infer type

Tags: swift, syntax-error

Can anyone explain why this single line block with an implicit `return` compiles:

```
let r = withUnsafePointer(&msg) {
    dn_expand(UnsafePointer($0), eomorig: UnsafePointer($0).advancedBy(msg.count), comp_dn: UnsafePointer($0).advancedBy(offset), exp_dn: &buf, length: buf.count)
}
```

but this version refactored where the only difference is to avoid the multiple calls to `UnsafePointer($0)` doesn't:

```
let s = withUnsafePointer(&msg) {
    let p = UnsafePointer($0)
    return dn_expand(p, eomorig: p.advancedBy(msg.count), comp_dn: p.advancedBy(offset), exp_dn: &buf, length: buf.count)
}
```

with error message:

> `Cannot convert value of type 'inout [UInt8]' (aka 'inout Array<UInt8>') to expected argument type 'inout _'`

The `dn_function` being called is just a trivial wrapper around `dn_expand` from `libresolv`:

```
public static func dn_expand(msg: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, eomorig: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, comp_dn: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, exp_dn: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>, length: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(res_9_dn_expand(msg, eomorig, comp_dn, exp_dn, Int32(length)))
}
```

Comment: What is the signature for `dn_expand`?

Comment: The compiler infers the type of a closure automatically only for *single-expression closures* or from the *context*, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/34115788/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR I suspected as such, but I cannot determine the correct explicit type myself

Comment: What type has `msg`?

Comment: @MartinR it's a `[UInt8]` (per the error message)

Comment: How does the single expression version compile in the first place? If msg is of type `[UInt8]`, `$0` is of type `UnsafePointer<[UInt8]>`. Do you have an extension that defines an `UnsafePointer.init` from `UnsafePointer<[UInt8]>` to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`? Anyhow, don't you wanna rather use `Array.withUnsafeBufferPointer`: `let s: Int = msg.withUnsafeBufferPointer { let p = $0.baseAddress; return ... }`

Comment: @ingoem  AFAIK you get "toll-free" bridging between `inout [UInt8]` and `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`, but I could be wrong...

Comment: Ah, it looks like `withUnsafeBufferPointer` may indeed be what I was missing!

Comment: @ingoem I perhaps meant bridging to `UnsafePointer<[UInt8]>` (NB `[...]`), rather than `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`.   I've certainly been able to pass via `inout x : [Type]` via `&x` directly to `UnsafePointer<Type>` on other functions, though.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, you can bridge between the two, but not in the way you originally wanted. You would be able to pass `&msg` to `dn_expand` directly without any of the `withUnsafe...` functions, but since you want to do pointer arithmetic with `advancedBy`, you have to use the `withUnsafe...` to get a handle to the pointer first.

Comment: @ingoem right, and it's the array-specific buffer pointer methods that I was previously unaware of that seem to be the "right way" in this case.  And yes, I was able to pass `&msg` for the first parameter, but not on the ones that required pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @ingoem if you'd like to write up an answer about using `withUnsafeBufferPointer` I'll happily accept :)

Comment: Thanks, Martin R beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in the comments, `withUnsafePointer()` is *not* the
correct way to get a pointer to the element storage. It compiles, but
gives unexpected results, as the following example demonstrates:

```
var msg: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

func foo(x: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) {
    print(x[0])
}

withUnsafePointer(&msg) {
    foo(UnsafePointer($0))
}
```

This prints "random" numbers, but not the expected `1`. The correct
way is to call the `withUnsafeBufferPointer()` method on the array:

```
msg.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    foo($0.baseAddress)
}
```

In your case that would be

```
let r = msg.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    dn_expand($0.baseAddress, eomorig: $0.baseAddress + $0.count, ...)
}
```

Here the return type of the closure is inferred automatically because
it is a "single-expression" closure. If the closure contains more
than one expression, you have to specify its type:

```
let r = msg.withUnsafeBufferPointer { bufPtr -> Int in
    let p = bufPtr.baseAddress
    return dn_expand(p, eomorig: p + msg.count, ...)
}
```

or let the compiler infer the return type from the *context:*

```
let r: Int = msg.withUnsafeBufferPointer { bufPtr in
    let p = bufPtr.baseAddress
    return dn_expand(p, eomorig: p + msg.count, ...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks (and also to @ingoem).  For some reason I never managed to find `Array.withUnsafeBufferPointer()` before! :p