# Infer closure return type from closure body when working with generics

Tags: swift

I think best if I start with an example:

```
class Test<T> {

    func test(closure: (T) -> Void) { }

    func test(closure: (T) -> T) { }

    func test(closure: (T) -> Test<T>) { }
}

Test<Int>().test { a in }
```

The code above gives the following error:

> error: ambiguous use of 'test'

This is because the Swift compiler doesn't know to which one of the three methods is should map the call to. But from the closure body it's quite clear that it returns a `Void`, so it should pick the first method.

Looks like the Swift compiler cannot determine to which method overload to map the call to based on the closure body. If I explicitly specify the closure signature, then the problem goes away:

```
Test<Int>().test { (a: Int) -> Void in }
```

My question is: can I somehow instruct Swift to pick-up the correct overload for short-hand closure expressions like the one in discussion, or will I have to explicitly declare the closure signature?

Comment: The closure type is inferred either from the context, or for "single-expression closures". `Test<Int>().test { _ in () }` seems to be the minimum you need.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the suggestion, is there something that will work for multi-statement closures?

Comment: There is no automatic type inference for multi-statement closures. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/34115788/1187415 for a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it seems that I was pushing the compiler limits too hard (as @Martin R pointed in the comments). The `{ a in }` closure was kinda incomplete, since the compiler had no statements to infer the closure return type from.

This works:

```swift
Test<Int>().test { (a: Int) -> Void in () }
```

Same as the following:

```swift
func doNothing() { }

Test<Int>().test { (a: Int) -> Void in doNothing() }
```

In the above examples the compiler is provided with the minimum amount of information to determine which overload to pick.