# How is Array() ambiguous when the given argument is a known type?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm seeing something that doesn't make sense to me.  Here's my code...

```
import Foundation

enum SeparatorPaddingLocation{
    case beforeSeparator
    case afterSeparator
}

struct SeparatorToken{
    let separator          : Character
    let formattedSeparator : String
    let paddingLocation    : SeparatorPaddingLocation
}

extension Array where Element == String {

    func aligned(separatorTokens:[SeparatorToken]) -> [String] {

        // This won't compile!
        let remainingSeparatorTokens = Array(separatorTokens.dropFirst())

        return self
    }
}
```

The 'let' causes this compile error even though `dropFirst()` returns an `ArraySlice<SeparatorToken>`.

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Why is this ambiguous? What am I missing?

I also tried fully qualifying it like so, but this didn't work either...

```
let remainingSeparatorTokens:[SeparatorToken] = Array(separatorTokens.dropFirst())
```

Comment: Isn't it inferred from the ArraySlice<SeparatorToken>?

Comment: Not sure what to say.  That's copied from my code and I'm running Xcode 9.2 (9C40b) as well.

Comment: Updated. I just pasted that exact code as-is in a playground and I *do* get the error. Strange!

Comment: I see the issue with your updated code. The difference is the function being in an `Array` extension.

Comment: I found a work-around, which is this `let remainingSeparatorTokens = [SeparatorToken](separatorTokens.dropFirst())` but I'm still unclear why this is ambiguous, just because it's in an extension. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Isn't it because your extension is qualified with `Element == String`? If you just say `let foo: [SeparatorToken] = Array()` you'll see the error that it can't convert `Array<String>` to type `[SeparatorToken]`. Use `let remainingSeparatorTokens = Array<SeparatorToken>(separatorTokens.dropFirst())` instead. Fixes the problem.

Comment: This is a known issue: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1789. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/37862276/2976878

Comment: Thanks @Hamish; I'd been hunting for that bug and was in the process of opening what would have been a dupe.

Comment: It's not a bug. See my answer. @Hamish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside of generic extensions, type parameters bind to their scope. I'm not sure this is really a good thing (or possibly if it's really a bug), but it shows up consistently, so the type parameter here implicitly wants to be `String`.

A simpler example:

```
let x = Array()  // error: generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred
```

That makes sense. But put it in an extension:

```
extension Array {
    func f() {
        let x = Array()
    }
}
```

This compiles, and `x` is of type `[Element]`.

In your case, you've set `Element` to `String`, so the call to `Array.init` wants to create a `[String]` and it's getting confused because `SeparatorToken != String`. You need to pass the type parameter explicitly (as you've discovered):

```
let remainingSeparatorTokens = Array<SeparatorToken>(separatorTokens.dropFirst())
```

Again, I don't really consider this a feature in Swift, and it may even be considered a bug. But it's very consistent.

Comment: Makes (annoying!) sense.  That said, is there a reason to use `Array<Type>(ArraySlice<Type>)` over the initializer as in `[Type](ArraySlice<Type>)`?  The latter is what I changed my code to use before I knew about the former.

Comment: While I like `[Type]` as a type, I think it reads very awkwardly as an implicit `init`. I believe `[T]()` is just too much punctuation, and too different from any other initializer in the system. But they compile to precisely the same thing, so it's stylistic. Much like using `() -> Void`, which I believe is better Swift than `() -> ()` even though they are identical.

Comment: Seems that closures have a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888880/infer-closure-return-type-from-closure-body-when-working-with-generics

Comment: Turns out that behavior is [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49243241/1610473).

Comment: @GreatBigBore I kinda feel this is a flaw in design, talking from a Swift developer perspective the compiler should be able to infer types in both directions if it has all the necessary information. Perhaps implementing something like this poses great challenges, that's why it's not yet available.

Comment: I wasn't talking about whether people feel it's a flaw. I was trying to correct the incorrect answers that have been posted. Flaw or not, it's clearly documented, intended behavior, absolutely not a bug.

Comment: Also, the compiler does not have all the necessary information. There is an obvious ambiguity that it can't address, as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just run your code in playground and updated as follows, then error is gone:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

enum SeparatorPaddingLocation{
    case beforeSeparator
    case afterSeparator
}

struct SeparatorToken{
    let separator          : Character
    let formattedSeparator : String
    let paddingLocation    : SeparatorPaddingLocation
}

extension Array where Element == String {

    func aligned(separatorTokens:[SeparatorToken]) -> [String] {

        // I update code here
        let remainingSeparatorTokens = Array<SeparatorToken>(separatorTokens.dropFirst())

        return self
    }
}
```

As per swift, Array required type when you going to initialise with Array.

I hope this will work for you.

For more details about array visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Comment: That's not entirely correct. If you place the `let` outside of the array extension you don't get a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a bug, and there's nothing mysterious or bug-like going on.

**Not a bug**: it's the very reason the `==` operator is available in `where` clauses: *to require `Element` to be of type `String`*, as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID553). Search the page for "you can also write a generic where clauses *that require Item to be a specific type*".

**Not bug-like**: when you're inside the extension and call an `Array` initializer, the compiler takes your `where` clause to indicate what specialization of `Array` you want. Your `where` clause says `String`, so `Array<String>` it is. The compiler can't read your mind when you pass an `ArraySlice<SeparatorToken>` into an `Array<String>` initializer. Did you make a mistake, or did you really want an `Array<ArraySlice<SeparatorToken>>`? Hence the error message about ambiguity.

Here's a simplified and annotated version of OP's code, in case anyone finds it illuminating.

```
class Foo<T> {
    var theFoo: T!

    init() { theFoo = nil }
    init(_ aFoo: T) { theFoo = aFoo }
}

extension Foo where T == Int {
    func bar() {
        // This one fails, because our where clause
        // says this extension applies to Foo<Int>,
        // but now we're trying to assign it to a Foo<String>
        let aFoo: Foo<String> = Foo()

        // This one also fails, for the same reason.
        // It uses the other initializer, but we're
        // still inside the Foo<Int> extension.
        let bFoo: Foo<String> = Foo("bFoo")

        // This one works, because we're expressly
        // overriding the where clause
        let cFoo: Foo<String> = Foo<String>("cFoo")
    }
}
```

The ambiguity error makes sense. I told the compiler in my `where` clause to make this an `Int` extension, so it created `Foo<Int>`s. But then I tried to assign those to variables of type `Foo<String>`. The compiler couldn't tell whether I really wanted `Foo<String>` or I had made a mistake, so it gave up.

Comment: But isn't `Array()` a top-level function? If so, why is it not inferring its type from what you pass in?  if you're saying because I'm inside an array (via an extension), then are you saying the array itself also defines a function called `Array()`? Isn't that confusing? I think so.  That's why I personally feel this is at least an oversight if not a bug.

Comment: It's inferring the type from your `where` clause. It's not because you're inside an extension. It's because you're inside an extension with a `where...==`. Try this `let foo: [SeparatorToken] = Array()` and you'll see the error that it can't convert `Array<String>` to type `[SeparatorToken]`. I'm not saying that `Array()` defines another `Array()` function. I'm saying that `==` in your `where` clause is doing exactly what the documentation says it will do: require `Element` to be of `String` type. That's why you have to qualify your `Array<SeparatorToken>` to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: But what I'm saying is how is it connecting the type of my 'where' to the element type of the Array function?  Put another way, say I wanted to write a similar function called NeatoArray() that behaved the same way as Array() does, inferring its type.  How would you code that?  Again, I understand there *is* this linking. I'm saying I don't understand *how* it's linking because I can use Array() outside of an extension so how is it implicitly picking that up?

Comment: ...unless it's not a function, but rather an initializer.  That would make more sense (and explain the connection as well as why I couldn't write a NeatoArray() function, but could write it if NeatoArray was a class itself.) In other words, I'm calling the initializer from within the extension so it would of course be inferred.

Comment: It's connecting your `where` type to `Array` because you're extending `Array`. Also, `Array` is a struct. So `Array()` is necessarily an initializer.