# With var, Swift says it cannot pass immutable value as inout argument

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, xcode8-beta6

I can't decipher this error message. This code compiles and runs

```
struct A {
    var x: Int
}
var a = A(x: 123)
let result = withUnsafePointer(to: &a) {
    print("ptr is \($0)")
    // return 1
}
print("result is \(result)")
```

But, if you uncomment that `return 1` line, the compile fails. Xcode highlights the `&a` and says: *Cannot pass immutable value of type 'inout A' as inout argument*.

What does that mean? Maybe it's just a buggy error message?

(Xcode 8, beta 6)

Comment: This most likely stems from the fact that the compiler can only infer the return type of a closure if it's a single expression, or from the calling context (see for example [Martin's answer on this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34115788/2976878)) – adding an explicit type annotation allows your code to compile. However you should probably [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org) on that useless error message

Comment: Thanks. Just filed the bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2501