# Use map to change struct property into new array

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift3

I am trying to create a new array from another array with some property changed. I followed the answer in this thread: [Using Map in Swift to Change Custom Struct Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113457/using-map-in-swift-to-change-custom-struct-properties), but I am not getting it to work, and get a crash in my PlayGround (XCode 8beta6)

Here is a simple example:

```
struct Day {
   var day: String
}

var mondays: [Day] = []

for i in 0..<10 {
   let day = Day(day: "Monday")

   mondays.append(day)
}

print(mondays)

// create a new array where all days have the day property set to 'Tuesday'
let tuesdays = mondays.map { (var d) -> Day in
   d.day = "Tuesday"
   return d
}

print(tuesdays)
```

Once I add the second part of the code I get a crash, with a long crashlog (which I will not reproduce here since it's too big). So it could just be a bug in Swift 3 and/or Xcode beta.

My question is, is there an error in my code, am I using the map correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [SE-0003](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md), `var` function parameters have been removed from Swift 3 (also see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164973/var-parameters-are-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-swift-3) on the topic). The fact that the compiler crashes instead of generating an error message telling you this, is a bug  – the compiler should never crash.

The solution is simply to simply create your own mutable copy of `map(_:)`'s function parameter.

```
let tuesdays = mondays.map { (d) -> Day in
    var d = d // mutable copy of d that shadows the immutable function argument d
    d.day = "Tuesday"
    return d
}
```

Comment: If not already, you should file a bug report for the compiler crash over at https://bugs.swift.org/

Comment: Bug report has been filed!