# Swift: Ambiguous reference to member 'map'

Tags: swift

I'm reading "The swift programming language 4.2". In the beginning chapter, page 23, I have this following requirement:

> Rewrite the closure to return zero for all odd number

And my solution is:

```
let myArray: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

myArray.map({ (number: Int) in 
   if number % 2 != 0 {
       return 0
   } else {
       return number
   }
})
```

But I have this following error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'map'

I really do not understand why I'm wrong, why my 'myArray' can not references to 'map' member?
Could you give me and explanation of this error and the right solution for this?
Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but where is the return type of the closure? And you logic for returning 0 for odd number is wrong. You are returning 0 for even numbers.

Comment: oh sorry :D I'm not focus on real logic now. I'll edit, thank you!

Comment: Sure but that won't return anything if you don't have the return type. Also your code compiles fine for me with return type.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your playrground with the error? (The full playground preferably)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113457/using-map-in-swift-to-change-custom-struct-properties: You have to provide the closures *return type*

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: I do not know how to upload image in the comment, so can you check it here? https://ibb.co/cwCRHz

Comment: Did you try adding the return type?

Comment: Yep, I tried and my code is working properly, thank for your help, you rock!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it less ambiguous by specifying the return type with `as [Int]`:

```
myArray.map({ (number: Int) in 
   if number % 2 != 0 {
       return 0
   } else {
       return number
   }
}) as [Int]
```

Or :

```
let result: [Int] = myArray.map({ (number: Int) in
    if number % 2 != 0 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return number
    }
})
print(result) //[0, 2, 0, 4, 0]
```

As noted by **vadian**: The ambiguity comes from the fact that the generic return type in the closure cannot be inferred.

To understand how the compiler infers the return type of a closure, let's go back to the syntax of a closure :

```
let myClosure: returnType = { (params) -> returnType in
    statements
}
```

Here, the type of `myClosure` is `returnType`. And it's set in two places: after `:`, and after `->`. You could use type inference by removing the `returnType` from one of the two places, but not both.

So you could remove it from inside the curly braces (like in the code above) :

```
let result: [Int] = myArray.map({ (number: Int) in
```

Or just after the variable name, and specifying the return type of the closure inside the the curly braces:

```
let result = myArray.map({ (number: Int) -> Int in
```

Comment: Where are you returning the number to? I don't see a return type anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I can not upvote your answer because of the new member policy :(

Comment: @yesterdayoncemore Glad I could help

Comment: *The ambiguity comes from the fact* that the generic return type in the closure cannot be inferred. A type can be `map`ped to any other even unrelated type. By the way you are discouraged from using the first (bridge cast) syntax.

Comment: @vadian In this case, only two types are possible: `[Int]` and `[Any]`. Yet, why isn't type inference working?

Comment: No, you can also return `"0"` and `String(number)`. Then the return type is `[String]` (in the closure `String`). That's the huge benefit of generics (the return type of the closure is `T`, a generic type).

Comment: @vadian returning strings isn't the point. in the original code, both return values are ints: 0 and number. It's probably a bug.

Comment: It's not a bug. If you specify the full closure you have to specify also the (static) return type of the **closure** (like in my answer) or to annotate the return type of the **function** like in your second example. In the latter case the compiler infers the closure return type from the annotation.

Comment: @yesterdayoncemore [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) could be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Rather than annotating the parameter type you have to specify the return type of the closure

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // You don't even need to annotate the array, the compiler knows the type.

let result = myArray.map({ number -> Int in
    if number % 2 != 0 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return number
    }
})
```

Or with trailing closure syntax and shorthand argument names. In this case the compiler can infer everything

```
let result = myArray.map { $0 % 2 != 0 ? 0 : $0 }
```

Comment: Thank for your help! Another nice solution that I can have! :)

Comment: The “automatic inference” is unrelated to trailing closure syntax or shorthand argument names, `myArray.map({ number in number % 2 != 0 ? 0 : number })` does compile as well. For *single expression closures* the return type is inferred automatically, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115788/1187415 (and I am tempted to close question this as a duplicate).