# Ambiguous reference to member 'map'

Tags: swift

So I have a two-dimensional array of Int

```
var boardArray = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 8), count: 8)
boardArray[4][4] = 1
```

Now I would like to get a two-dimensional array of String.
0 -> "-"
1 -> "*"

```
let z = boardArray.map{a in a.map{v in 
       if v == 0 {
            return "-"
        }
        else {
            return "*"
        }

        } }
```

And so I have a compile-time error 'Ambiguous reference to member 'map''. What should I do?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130723/swift-ambiguous-reference-to-member-map

Comment: `let z: [[String]] = boardArray.map { array in
    array.map { $0 == 0 ? "-" : "*" }
}`